# Reasoning behind the formula to determine the number of fused polygons

Tags: geometry, polygons

I'm trying to find the reasoning behind the following formula to determine the number of fused polygons $N$, which I found in my Organic Chemistry textbook:

$$S-A+1=N$$

where $S$ is the number of edges, and $A$ is the number of vertices.

I verified the above formula for different combinations of polygons, and it worked flawlessly in all cases I considered. The following image shows two of the different configurations I considered and the application of the above formula giving the corresponding number of fused polygons:

[image]

It works irrespective of the number of common edges. Is this formula an empirical (just based on observations) or is there any good reason behind it? Further, are there any exceptions to this formula?

**Edit:**

Example to address the comments below the question:

[image]

$30-24+1=7$

Comment: The formula does not always hold. Consider a "ring" of six hexagons where $S-A+1=30-24+1=7\not=6=N$.

Comment: @mathlove: Hi. A ring of six hexagons includes a seventh hexagon in the middle. Even though I doubt the correctness of the formula, here I feel it works really well.

Comment: "A ring of six hexagons includes a seventh hexagon in the middle" No, it doesn't at all. A ring is a shape with a hole. Notice, from the example I showed, that the formula does not work when there are *holes*. If you want to avoid holes, then you have to write that explicitly.

Comment: @mathlove: In order to avoid confusion, I've made an edit to my question including the example suggested by you. Thanks.

Comment: What you added have seven hexagons. My example has six hexagons, not seven because my example is a "ring" without the middle hexagon. I'm still unsure if you want to avoid holes. If you want to avoid holes, then you have to write that explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are holes, then the formula does not hold as I've already commented.

Without holes, the formula holds.

In the following, let us consider fused polygons without holes.

The reason why the formula holds is that if you add a new hexagon to fused polygons, then the following relation $$(\text{the number of the added edges})-(\text{the number of the added vertices})=1$$ holds.

---

One can prove that the formula holds by induction on the number of polygons.

*Proof* :

If we consider one hexagon, then $S=A=6$, so $S-A+1=N$ holds.

Suppose that $S_F-A_F+1=N$ holds in the fused polygons $F$.

- **Case 1** : If you add one hexagon $H$ to $F$ where $H$ and $F$ has exactly one common edge, then in the new polygons $F'$, we have $$N_{F'}=N+1,\quad S_{F'}=S_F+5,\quad A_{F'}=A_F+4$$So, we see that $S_{F'}-A_{F'}+1=N_{F'}$ holds.
- **Case 2** : If you add one hexagon $H$ to $F$ where $H$ and $F$ has exactly two common edges (note that the two edges have to be adjacent), then in the new polygons $F'$, we have $$N_{F'}=N+1,\quad S_{F'}=S_F+4,\quad A_{F'}=A_F+3$$So, we see that $S_{F'}-A_{F'}+1=N_{F'}$ holds.
- **Case 3** : If you add one hexagon $H$ to $F$ where $H$ and $F$ has exactly three common edges (note that the three edges have to be adjacent), then in the new polygons $F'$, we have $$N_{F'}=N+1,\quad S_{F'}=S_F+3,\quad A_{F'}=A_F+2$$So, we see that $S_{F'}-A_{F'}+1=N_{F'}$ holds.
- **Case 4** : If you add one hexagon $H$ to $F$ where $H$ and $F$ has exactly four common edges (note that the four edges have to be adjacent), then in the new polygons $F'$, we have $$N_{F'}=N+1,\quad S_{F'}=S_F+2,\quad A_{F'}=A_F+1$$So, we see that $S_{F'}-A_{F'}+1=N_{F'}$ holds.
- **Case 5** : If you add one hexagon $H$ to $F$ where $H$ and $F$ has exactly five common edges, then in the new polygons $F'$, we have $$N_{F'}=N+1,\quad S_{F'}=S_F+1,\quad A_{F'}=A_F$$So, we see that $S_{F'}-A_{F'}+1=N_{F'}$ holds.

From the five cases above, the formula holds for $N+1$. $\quad\square$

Comment: `+1` Thank you for your answer. With reference to "Case 5": Could you explain how to draw a hexagon with five common edges with another hexagon? I think we'd get the same hexagon. Then will it not lead to extra counts i.e., counting a single hexagon as two and so on?

Comment: @GuruVishnu: You are welcome. "a hexagon with five common edges with another hexagon" No, that's not what my answer said. What my answer said is that one hexagon $H$ and **fused polygons $F$** have five common edges. $F$ is not a single hexagon. $F$ is fused polygons which have $N$ hexagons. If you need, I'll draw a figure.

Comment: Ok. Now, I understood this point. If possible, could you explain what is meant by "holes"? I was unable to understand this since your first comment to my question. I count a region as a polygon when it can be filled with different colours in Microsoft Paint. But here I think you are referring to something else.

Comment: @GuruVishnu: By "holes", I mean the space where there is no polygons, but surrounded by polygons. What you added in the question has seven hexagons. My example has six hexagons since my ring does not have the middle hexagon. The shape of the middle space of my ring is a hexagon, but my understanding of "fused polygons" allows me to have a ring. Anyway, it depends on what you meant by "fused". I think that my ring is a "fused" polygons, but you might not think so.

Comment: May I know whether are you considering any three-dimensional fused polygons? This is the only example where six hexagons have a "hole" which can't be counted as a polygon. Did I get your idea correctly?

Comment: @GuruVishnu: No, I'm not considering them. "I count a region as a polygon when it can be filled with different colours in Microsoft Paint" In my ring, I don't count a hole as a polygon even though the shape of the hole is a hexagon because my ring is a *fused polygons* in my opinion. I think here is our difference. Why not stop this conversation?:) No problem for me if you don't consider any holes.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this equation by induction on the number of edges: When you remove an edge, you reduce either the number of vertices or the number of (closed) polygons by one.

This is a specific case of the more general fact that the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) is a topological constant. You can relate it to the more well-known case $V-E+F=2$, where $V$, $E$ and $F$ are the numbers of vertices, edges and faces of a polyhedron, respectively, by applying [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) to map the plane to the unit sphere and noting that the infinite domain outside the polygons gets mapped to an additional face of the resulting polyhedron.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm having a doubt in this statement: "_When you remove an edge, you reduce either the number of vertices or the number of (closed) polygons by one._": When removing an edge I can see how we reduce the number of polygons. But I don't see how it affects the number of vertices at least when there is only a single common edge.

Comment: @GuruVishnu: I don't know what you mean by "there is only a single common edge". Please provide an example (ideally relating to the two examples in your question).

Comment: Fine. Let us consider the first example in the question. When removing the common edge, I don't see any variation in the number of vertices. Could you say where I'm wrong?

Comment: @GuruVishnu: There isn't a change in the number of vertices, and there shouldn't be, since in this case the number of polygons is reduced by $1$.

Comment: Thank you. If possible, could you provide an example where removing an edge has an effect on the number of vertices over the number of polygons?

Comment: @GuruVishnu: For example, if you remove two adjacent (non-common) edges from the left-hand polygon, removing the second one removes a vertex. But I suggest to focus more on the second paragraph (including the link) than on the first. The first paragraph is just my brief summary of a proof idea that you may want to write out in more detail. The second paragraph gives you a better general idea and access to lots of existing proofs (including through the link).